# Valores do input radio permanecer dentro de um array

Tags: jquery

Não sei se fui claro na minha pergunta, mas tenho o seguinte formulário:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando é adicionado mais um campo e quando é selecionado por exemplo Crianças de colo? no segundo campo, ele desmarca o primeiro. Vejam abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso fazer para que selecionando sempre os outros campos criados, os anteriores permaneçam com seus valores marcados?

```
<table border="0" width="100%">
<tr class='linhas'>
  <td>
  <table border="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
    <td  style="padding: 5px"><input type="text" name="NomePAX[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome do pax" value=""></td>
    <td  style="padding: 5px">
      <select name="TipoDocumento" class="form-control">
        <option>Tipo de documento</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td  style="padding: 5px">
      <input type="text" name="RGPessoaAutorizada[]" class="form-control" placeholder="RG da pessoa autorizada" value="">
      <!-- <input type="text" name="CPF" id="cpf" class="form-control" data-inputmask="'alias': '999.999.999-99'"> -->
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td style="padding: 5px">
    <label>Crianças de colo? <small>até 06 anos</small></label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="CriancasColo[]" value="Sim"> Sim
    <input type="radio" name="CriancasColo[]" value="Não"> Não
  </td>
  <td  style="padding: 5px">
    <label>Crianças entre 06 e 12 anos?</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="Criancas6e12[]" value="Sim"> Sim
    <input type="radio" name="Criancas6e12[]" value="Não"> Não
  </td>
  <td  style="padding: 5px">
    <label>Adolescentes entre 12 e 18 anos?</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="Adolescentes[]" value="Sim"> Sim
    <input type="radio" name="Adolescentes[]" value="Não"> Não
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
    <td style="padding: 5px"><button type="button" class="removerCampo btn btn-danger" title="Remover linha"><i class="fa fa-minus-square" aria-hidden="true"></i> Remover</button></td>
<tr>
    <td colspan="3"><button type="button" class="adicionarCampo btn btn-primary" title="Adicionar item"><i class="fa fa-plus-square" aria-hidden="true"></i> Adicionar mais passageiros</button></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**JQuery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(function () {
       function removeCampo() {
             $(".removerCampo").unbind("click");
             $(".removerCampo").bind("click", function () {
                if($("tr.linhas").length > 1){
                     $(this).parent().parent().remove();
                }
             });
       }
       $(".adicionarCampo").click(function () {
         if ($('.linhas').length < 15) {
             novoCampo = $("tr.linhas:first").clone();
             novoCampo.find('input[type="text"]').val("");
             novoCampo.find('select').val("");
             novoCampo.insertAfter("tr.linhas:last");
             removeCampo();
           }
       });
     });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> O que ocorre é que quando você marca uma opção `RADIO`, esta será desmarcada quando você selecionar outra opção `RADIO` com mesmo `NAME`.
>
> Você tem que mudar os `name` dos inputs `RADIO` de cada campo criado

Nos inputs type `RADIO` do seu HTML substitua os colchetes nos `name` pelo digito 0 (zero) e acrescente uma `class` a cada grupo conforme indicado no código HTML abaixo

```
<tr>
  <td style="padding: 5px">
    <label>Crianças de colo? <small>até 06 anos</small></label><br>
    <input type="radio" class="CriancasColo" name="CriancasColo0" value="Sim"> Sim
    <input type="radio" class="CriancasColo" name="CriancasColo0" value="Não"> Não
  </td>
  <td  style="padding: 5px">
    <label>Crianças entre 06 e 12 anos?</label><br>
    <input type="radio" class="Criancas6e12" name="Criancas6e120" value="Sim"> Sim
    <input type="radio" class="Criancas6e12" name="Criancas6e120" value="Não"> Não
  </td>
  <td  style="padding: 5px">
    <label>Adolescentes entre 12 e 18 anos?</label><br>
    <input type="radio" class="Adolescentes" name="Adolescentes0" value="Sim"> Sim
    <input type="radio" class="Adolescentes" name="Adolescentes0" value="Não"> Não
  </td>
</tr>
```

Na função `adicionarCampo` acrescente essas linhas

```
var x = ($('.linhas').length);
novoCampo.find('.CriancasColo').attr('name', 'CriancasColo' + x);
novoCampo.find('[name*=CriancasColo]').prop('checked',false);
novoCampo.find('.Criancas6e12').attr('name', 'Criancas6e12' + x);
novoCampo.find('[name*=Criancas6e12]').prop('checked',false);
novoCampo.find('.Adolescentes').attr('name', 'Adolescentes' + x);
novoCampo.find('[name*=Adolescentes]').prop('checked',false);
```

**Função adicionarCampo**

```
$(".adicionarCampo").click(function () {
    if ($('.linhas').length < 15) {
        novoCampo = $("tr.linhas:first").clone();
        novoCampo.find('input[type="text"]').val("");
         
        var x = ($('.linhas').length);
        novoCampo.find('.CriancasColo').attr('name', 'CriancasColo' + x);
        novoCampo.find('[name*=CriancasColo]').prop('checked',false);
         
        novoCampo.find('.Criancas6e12').attr('name', 'Criancas6e12' + x);
        novoCampo.find('[name*=Criancas6e12]').prop('checked',false);
         
        novoCampo.find('.Adolescentes').attr('name', 'Adolescentes' + x);
        novoCampo.find('[name*=Adolescentes]').prop('checked',false);
         
        novoCampo.find('select').val("");
        novoCampo.insertAfter("tr.linhas:last");
        removeCampo();
    }
});
```

> OBS: caso você marque os inputs Radios antes de criar novos campos, estes novos campos virão com os inputs marcados tal qual o anterior. Para evitar esse fato acrescentamos `.prop('checked',false);` para cada novo campo criado.

Comment: Perfeito qualcuno. Funcionou! Muito obrigado!